# Overload due to apache process and Mysql process

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, process, cpu

I have a small site running and only 20 suppliers used to access this sites for queries. The server is running on high load during the peak hours. Please find the output below:

```
top - 10:15:42 up 32 days, 20:08,  4 users,  load average: 2.20, 2.06, 1.94
Tasks: 500 total,   1 running, 498 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  7.1%us,  2.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 90.6%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32931056k total,  3124852k used, 29806204k free,    49508k buffers
Swap:  3999740k total,        0k used,  3999740k free,  1364836k cached

 PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
10130 mysql     20   0 6207m 567m 5468 S  232  1.8  14306:04 mysqld
27534 worldsto  20   0  307m  20m 5364 S    5  0.1   0:01.97 apache2
29237 worldsto  20   0  299m  12m 3696 S    2  0.0   0:00.07 apache2
29003 worldsto  20   0  299m  13m 3716 S    1  0.0   0:00.12 apache2

root@server70:~# ps -ef | grep apache | wc
    434    2368   17756

CPU(s):     24
RAM size:   32 GB
```

From what I have seen from the Apache logs, all the connections are coming from suppliers and company IP addresses. I am sure there is something wrong with the Apache process so that MYSQL is using more CPU load. 
Please someone help me to identify and fix this problem. Thanks

Comment: Pls check you web application, it may be using lots mysql heavy queries etc...

Comment: there is nowhere near enough information here to solve your problem. its almost certainly down to crappy non indexed queries. a load average of two is not high, unless you're on a single or dual core machine.

Comment: My home page is loading fine but after login to the home page, it is taking more than 3 min for a listing single query. Can you please tell me how i can check the quires on web application? How i can resolve this problem?

Comment: Architecture:  x86_64, CPU op-mode(s): 32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:  Little Endian
CPU(s): 24
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-23
Thread(s) per core: 2
Core(s) per socket: 6
Socket(s): 2
NUMA node(s):   4
Vendor ID:  AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            21
Model:                 1
CPU MHz:  1400.000
BogoMIPS:   4799.93
Virtualisation:        AMD-V
NUMA node0 CPU(s):0-5
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     6-11
NUMA node2 CPU(s):12-17
NUMA node3 CPU(s):18-23
Please find my cpu information. How i can identify non indexed queries? Is it possible to kill those quires to improve site performance? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best troubleshooting step you can do is this:

connect to your MySQL server process, and type:

`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`

That will show you every query that's running. You will probably see the same query showing up multiple times, perhaps with different ID's - maybe something like:

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooid='1'
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE fooid='2'
...etc...`

That means you need an index on 'fooid'.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Please find the output below

Comment: Hi Sorry. from the mysql process list i can see lots of sleeping process from the local host. Please find the example below                            20115336 | ws_db_user | localhost | worldstores_db | Sleep   | 6445 |                              | NULL

Comment: Then those connections to your database are idle. You may need to run the command a few times while you're dealing with your 'high-load' situation - and then you should have some more interesting information to share. Nine times out of ten? It's a missing DB index.